# Installation Software DVDs on Macbook Pro MC721ZA/A

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, install, dvd

I bought MacBook Pro today, when I reached home, I unboxed its contents, but I didn't find any Software DVD for Mac OS Lion installation. I called the seller, he told me that there are no Software DVDs included since Mac OS Lion installed Macbook Pros. He said there is a process by which you can re-install the OS without using DVD. He will let me know of which by Monday.

I like to make sure that what he said is that true?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it has Lion pre-installed then you have no DVD's.  If you hold option while booting up, it will allow you to boot into a recovery HD to reinstall the OS.

Comment: okies so whenever new/fresh installation is needed all I need to do is restart and hold option key while booting and it will move into recovery mode and can install fresh Lion OS copy?

Comment: Yup. You can also hold CMD + R and it will be right into the recovery HD. This unfort doesn't help you if your HD dies. In that case, you could buy the recovery USB stick from Apple.  For people that upgraded to Lion from Snow Leopard, it was fairly easy to make a USB boot device using a 4GB flash drive.  Apple has basically said that if you end up with a bum HD with no way to boot to recover Lion, they'd take care of you. I think that means they will send you the Lion USB installer that they sell for $69

Comment: Ah, I also forgot about this tool that you could make as a backup http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1433